# SLLN for V-statistics - Strong consistency of distance covariance in metric spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

I'm trying to understand the proof for strong consistency of distance covariance in metric spaces (Proposition 2.6 [Distance covariance in metric spaces by Russel Lyons](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.5758.pdf) published in The Annals of Probability).

Let $(\mathcal{X},d_1)$ and $(\mathcal{Y},d_2)$ be two metric spaces and $((X_k,Y_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an i.i.d sequence of random elements with values in $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$ such that 
$$
Ed_1(X_1,x')<\infty \quad \quad and \quad \quad Ed_2(Y_1,y')<\infty, 
$$
for any $x'\in \mathcal{X}$ and $y'\in\mathcal{Y} $. The distance covariance $dcov(X,Y)$ is given by
$$
dcov(X,Y) = Eh((X_{1},Y_1),...,(X_6,Y_6)),
$$
where 
\begin{align*}
h((x_{1},y_1),...,(x_6,y_6))=&f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)f_2(y_1,y_2,y_5,y_6) ,\\
\end{align*}
and
$$
f_i(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) =d_i(z_1,z_2)-d_i(z_1,z_3)-d_i(z_2,z_4)+d_i(z_3,z_4).
$$
The emperical distance covariance hence becomes a $V$-statistic with (in general) non-symmetric kernel $h$ of degree $6$, i.e.
$$
dcov_n(X,Y) = \frac{1}{n^6} \sum_{i_1=1}^n \cdots \sum_{i_6=1}^n h((X_{i_1},Y_{i_1}),...,(X_{i_6},Y_{i_6})).
$$
Now it is stated without reference to a SLLN that $dcov_n(X,Y) \to dcov(X,Y)$ almost surely.

**Problem:**
The weakest conditions for SLLN for $V$-statistics I know require that

> The kernel $h$ is symmetric and \begin{align*} E| h((X_{i_1},Y_{i_1}),...,(X_{i_6},Y_{i_6}))|^{\frac{\#\{i_1,...,i_6\}}{6}} < \infty, \end{align*} for any $1 \leq i_1 \leq \cdots \leq i_6 \leq 6$.

So my approach was to let $\tilde{h}$ be the symmetrized version of $h$: $$\tilde{h}((x_1,y_1),...,(x_6,y_6))=\frac{1}{6!} \sum_{\sigma\in \Pi_6} h((x_{\sigma(1)},y_{\sigma(1)}),...,(x_{\sigma(6)},y_{\sigma(6)})),$$
where $\Pi_6$ is the set of all permutations on $\{1,...,6\}$. Then the above conditions of the SLLN reduces to
\begin{align*}
E| h((X_{i_1},Y_{i_1}),...,(X_{i_6},Y_{i_6}))|^{\frac{\#\{i_1,...,i_6\}}{6}} < \infty,
\end{align*}
for all $(i_1,...,i_6)\in \{1,...,6\}^6$.

The only way (that i can see) we can create upper bounds for $h$ is by the triangle inequality, which amounts to the following inequalities (suppressing the $i$ index in the metric)

\begin{align}
\frac{|f_i(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)|}{2}\leq \left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
d(z_1,z_4), & d(z_2,z_3), & d(z_1,z_2) \lor d(z_1,z_3), \\
d(z_1,z_2) \lor d(z_1,z_4), & d(z_1,z_2) \lor d(z_2,z_3), & d(z_1,z_2) \lor d(z_2,z_4), \\
d(z_1,z_4)  \lor d(z_1,z_3), & d(z_1,z_4)  \lor d(z_2,z_3), & d(z_1,z_4)  \lor d(z_2,z_4), \\
d(z_2,z_3) \lor d(z_1,z_3), & d(z_2,z_3) \lor d(z_2,z_4),  & d(z_3,z_4) \lor d(z_1,z_3), \\ 
d(z_3,z_4) \lor d(z_1,z_4), & d(z_3,z_4) \lor d(z_2,z_3), &d(z_3,z_4) \lor d(z_2,z_4). \\  \end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
and we realize that if for example $i_1=i_2$ then every combination of the above inequalities result in
$$
E| h((X_{i_1},Y_{i_1}),...,(X_{i_6},Y_{i_6}))|^{\frac{\#\{i_1,...,i_6\}}{6}} \leq 4E([\gamma(X_{i_1},...)\theta(Y_{i_1},...)]^{\frac{\#\{i_1,...,i_6\}}{6}}),
$$
where $\gamma$ and $\theta$ is any of the above upper bounds.

We know that $E\gamma(X_{i_1},...)<\infty$ and $E\theta(Y_{i_1},...)<\infty$, for example
$$
Ed(X_{i_2},X_{i_3}) \lor d(X_{i_1},X_{i_3}) \leq E d(X_{i_2},x')+d(X_{i_3},x')+d(X_{i_1},x')+d(X_{i_3},x') < \infty.
$$
But we can't use independence to split up the expectation since $X_{i_1}$ may not be independent of $Y_{i_1}$. I realize that if $\#\{i_1,...,i_6\}\leq 3$ then Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be used to say that
\begin{align*}
4E([\gamma(X_{i_1},...)\theta(Y_{i_1},...)]^{\frac{\#\{i_1,...,i_6\}}{6}})&\leq 4E([\gamma(X_{i_1},...)\theta(Y_{i_1},...)]^{1/2})+4 \\
&\leq 4[E\gamma(X_{i_1},...)]^{1/2}[E\theta(Y_{i_1},...)]^{1/2} +4< \infty,
\end{align*}
but if $3<\#\{i_1,...,i_6\}\leq 6$, then we can't utilize this either.

***Thus: Is there another version of SLLN for $V$-statistics which is suitable in this situation,  or is there another way to bound the above expectation?***

Comment: "Now it is proclaimed without proof that $dcov_n(X,Y) \to dcov(X,Y)$ almost surely." You didn't read the article carefully. Each statement there is proved (I would be surprised if an article with some unproved central results were published in AoP).

Comment: As I read it: First he shows that $h((X_1,Y_1),..,(X_6,Y_6))$ is integrable (under the assumption that $(X_1,Y_1),...,(Y_1,Y_6)$ are independent), showing that $dcov(\theta)$ is the expression I defined it as in the question . After this it reads "$dcov(\theta_n) [=dcov_n(X,Y)]$ are the V-statistics for the kernel $h$ of degree $6$. Hence, the result follows." So I took the liberty of saying without proof, since non of the SLLN conditions are proven satisfied. Unless there is a SLLN for V-statistics which only require the kernel to be integrable when the indices of its arguments are distinct.

Comment: @zhoraster  - I changed the sentence, to reflect that a SLLN theorem isn't referenced instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the place is not properly explained in the article.

The problem is to show the integrability of $f_1(X_{i_1},X_{i_2},X_{i_3},X_{i_4})f_2(Y_{i_1},Y_{i_2},Y_{i_5},Y_{i_6})$ for all $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_6$, not just for distinct ones. First assume that $i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4$ are distinct and $i_1,i_2,i_5,i_6$ are distinct. Here one can employ other ideas of the article in order to establish the integrability. Namely, it is easy to see that
$$
f_1(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) =d_\mu(z_1,z_2)-d_\mu(z_1,z_3)-d_\mu(z_2,z_4)+d_\mu(z_3,z_4).\tag{1}
$$
Then we can estimate, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\mathbb E[f_1(X_{i_1},X_{i_2},X_{i_3},X_{i_4})f_2(Y_{i_1},Y_{i_2},Y_{i_5},Y_{i_6})] \\\le \big(\mathbb E[f_1(X_{i_1},X_{i_2},X_{i_3},X_{i_4})^2]\mathbb E[f_2(Y_{i_1},Y_{i_2},Y_{i_5},Y_{i_6})^2]\big)^{1/2}
$$
Further, by (1)
$$
\mathbb E[f_1(X_{i_1},X_{i_2},X_{i_3},X_{i_4})^2]\\\le 4\big(\mathbb E[d_\mu(X_{i_1},X_{i_2})^2] + \mathbb E[d_\mu(X_{i_1},X_{i_3})^2] + \mathbb E[d_\mu(X_{i_2},X_{i_4})^2] + \mathbb E[d_\mu(X_{i_3},X_{i_4})^2]\big).
$$
But $\mathbb E[d_\mu(X_{i},X_{j})^2] <\infty$ for $i\neq j$ (Lemma 2.1 of the article). Similarly,
$$
\mathbb E[f_2(Y_{i_1},Y_{i_2},Y_{i_5},Y_{i_6})^2]<\infty,
$$
qed.

When there are two coincidences, one can use Cauchy-Schwarz to proceed.

So let there be a single coincidence in some of $i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4$ be equal. If $i_1\neq i_2$, then we can proceed as in the article. Say, if $i_2=i_3$, we can estimate $f_1(X_{i_1},X_{i_2},X_{i_3},X_{i_4})\le g_1(X_{i_2},X_{i_3},X_{i_4})$, $f_2(\dots)\le g_2(Y_{i_1},Y_{i_5},Y_{i_6})$.

So the only remaining case is $i_1=i_2$. Here
$$
h = \big(d_1(X_{i_3},X_{i_4})-d_1(X_{i_1},X_{i_3})-d_1(X_{i_1},X_{i_4})\big) \big(d_2(Y_{i_5},Y_{i_6})-d_2(Y_{i_1},Y_{i_5})-d_2(Y_{i_1},Y_{i_6})\big).
$$
Upon expanding, there are many well-behaved terms. Ill-behaved come with the same (positive) sign and all of the same kind, so it is necessary and sufficient to establish the convergence of
$$
\frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n d_1(X_i,X_j)d_2(Y_i,Y_k)
$$
to zero. In turn, for the latter it is sufficient to have
$$
\mathbb{E}[d_1(X,X')^{3/4}d_2(Y,Y'')^{3/4}]<\infty,\tag{1}
$$
where $(X,Y)$ has the given distribution, and $X'$, $Y''$ have the given marginal distribution, and $(X,Y),X',Y''$ are independent. Assumption (1) might be necessary too, as for the classical Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund SLLN a similar condition is necessary. It does not seem though that (1) follows from the assumptions of the article. So I suggest you to inquire the author, how he deals with this.

---

UPD (from the discussion): here is an [errata](https://dlyons.pages.iu.edu/errata/dcov.pdf) for original paper and [Janson's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.13358.pdf), which shows that the consistency holds in the original formulation.

Comment: It does not hold that $Ed_\mu(X,X)^2=0$, since $d_\mu(x,x)<0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{X}$ (see Remark 2.2.). Also note that \begin{align*}
 Ed_\mu(X,X)^2&= E[\left(d_1(X,X) -a_\mu(X)-a_\mu(X)  +D(\mu)\right)^2] \\
 &=E[ \left(2a_\mu(X)-D(\mu)\right)^2]\\
 &=E[4a_\mu(X)^2 +D(\mu)^2 -4D(\mu)a_\mu(X)] \\
 &=4Ea_\mu(X)^2 +D(\mu)^2 -4D(\mu)Ea_\mu(X) \\
 &=4Ea_\mu(X)^2 -3D(\mu)^2
 \end{align*}
 and this is finite if and only if

Comment: (not if and only if, just if) \begin{align*}
  Ea_\mu(X)^2 &=  \int \left( \int d(x,y) dP_X(y) \right)^2 dP_X(x) \\
  &\leq Ed(X_1,X_2)^2 \\
  &\leq 2Ed(X_1,x)^2 -2Ed(X_1,x)Ed(X_1,x) \\
  &< \infty
      \end{align*}
 and since $2Ed(X_1,x)^2$ beyond our assumptions, we can't say anything about this either. Any idea on how one might bound $Ea_\mu(X)^2$ by something we know if finite?

Comment: @Martin, you're right, I'll think about this.

Comment: @Martin, I've updated, the (no-)answer with some further thoughts. Finally, I believe it is best to write to the author.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort @zhoraster, it is greatly appreciated - I will award you the bounty. I wrote the author about eight days ago, and I recieved no answer yet, so I don't think any will come. I'm going to write up a question on MathOverflow within the next few days, containing our problems and approaches - Maybe someone in there will be able to find a solution or a counterexample.

Comment: I think that this thread deserves an update. I got in contact with the author and we discussed the problem. The author have addressed the issue in the following errata: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-46/issue-4/Errata-to-Distance-covariance-in-metric-spaces/10.1214/17-AOP1233.short

Comment: @John, unfortunately, I don't have an access to the errata. Feel free to complement my answer; I made it community wiki.

Comment: The errata is also available here: rdlyons.pages.iu.edu/errata/dcov.pdf . It shows that whenever the metric spaces are of negative type then the theorem holds. However, more recently in arxiv.org/pdf/1910.13358.pdf  it is shown that the strong consistency holds in its original formulation.

Comment: @John, thanks for the links! I added them to my answer.